# How do we get Sellable or varient images through commerce api?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api

I have added the images in sitecore sellable item but in not getting the Images Detail in Sellable Api.

```
{{ServiceHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/SellableItems('NYRR Catalog,20001,20003')?$expand=Components($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents($expand=ChildComponents)))))
```

Comment: Can you please post the result of your call? In general xc just saves sitecore xp item id of media lib item,with which you can then grab the image behind the media item.

Comment: In your example above you are asking for a specific variant (20003). Does that variant have an Image? Do you see it in BizFx? If you want to load the whole Sellable Item entity and components remove the variant from the Url.
Normally you should see the Images Component if Sellable Items has any. Don't need any customization.